# How to make multiple observations with Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to make multiple observations, but I don't know how.

Here is my database structure:

```
"Posts" : {
"f934f8j3f8" : {
  "data" : "",
  "date" : "",
  "userid" : "" 
}
},  
"Users" : {
"BusWttqaf9bWP224EQ6lOEJezLO2" : {
  "Country" : "",
  "DOB" : "",
  "Posts" : {
    "f934f8j3f8" : true
  },
  "Profilepic" : "",
  "name" : "",
  "phonenumber" : ""
}
```

I want to observe the posts and I write the code and it works great, but I also want to get the name of the user who posted this post but when I wrote save the name and use it it gives me null. Here is my code.

```
DataServices.ds.REF_POSTS.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, 
                       with: { (snapshot) in

     self.posts = []

     if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

         for snap in snapshot {

             if let postsDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

                let key = snap.key

                let userID = "BusWttqaf9bWP224EQ6lOEJezLO2"
                DataServices.ds.REF_USERS.child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let postusername = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                })
                print(" ------ User name : \(postusername) ------")
              })

              print(" ------ User name 2 : \(postusername) ------")

              let post = Posts(postKey: key, postData: postsDict)
              self.posts.append(post)
```

The first print statement prints the username, but the second one prints nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've included a link to picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is asynchronous so you can't operate on a variable until Firebase populates it within it's closure. Additionally code is faster than the internet so any statements following a closure will occur *before* the statements within the closure.

The flow would be as follows

```
Query for the post {
  get the user id from the post inside this closure
  query for the user info {
     create the post inside this second closure
     append the data to the array inside this second closure
     reload tableview etc inside this second closure
  }
}
```

Something like this edited code

```
self.posts = []
myPostsRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


 if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
   for snap in snapshot {
        if let postsDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            let key = snap.key

            let userID = "BusWttqaf9bWP224EQ6lOEJezLO2"
            myUsersRef.child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let userName = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let post = Posts(postKey: key, postData: postsDict, name:userName)
                self.posts.append(post)
            })
         }
    }
  }
})
```

You're not using the postusername inside the closure so I added that to the Posts initialization.

Also, the self.posts = [] is going to reset the posts array any time there's a change in the posts node - you may want to consider loading the array first, and then watch for adds, changes, or deletes and just update the posts array with single changes instead of reloading the entire array each time.

Edit:

A comment was made about the data not being available outside the loop. Here is a very simplified and tested version. Clicking button one populates the array from Firebase with a series of strings, clicking button 2 prints the array.

```
var posts = [String]()

func doButton1Action() {

    let postsRef = ref.child("posts")
    self.posts = []
    postsRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                let value = snap.value as! String
                self.posts.append(value)
            }
        }
    })

}

func doButton2Action() {
    print(posts)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay. Although I have used your code but the same problem remained. Outside this function the posts array is empty so I am not able to use the data !

Comment: @MohamedYassin You can't use the array until it's completed populating from within the closure. So for example, right after the for snap in snapshot loop, reload your tableview, which will populate it from the array. Once the tableView has been populated from within the closure what else are you trying to do with it?

Comment: When I use for example posts.count for giving the number of rows it gives me zero !

Comment: @MohamedYassin My guess is there's some other issue. I have updated my answer with a tested and fully functional example.